# In Ubuntu OS "Gill san MT" Font is not supported

Tags: fonts, kendo-ui

I am doing a project based on kendo ui controls.In my application I am applying" Font-Family:"Gill san MT"" font for total body.It is working in windows 7.But when we run my application on Ubuntu,the font is displaying as "Times New Roman".Its happen only in Ubuntu.Why its happening?Is Ubuntu supported for Gill san MT font?Any one reply me please?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This belongs on `askubuntu.com`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, the font is called "[Gill Sans](http://en.wikipedia.org/Gill_Sans)", not "Gill san".

Second of all, no, the font won't display correctly if it isn't installed. Gill Sans is not even installed by default on Windows; it's definitely not installed on Ubuntu unless the user's gone out and installed it themselves. To cope with situations like this, your web site should specify appropriate fallback fonts:

```
font-family: "Gill Sans", sans-serif;
```

and you may want to look into getting [a web font version of Gill Sans](http://www.webtype.com/font/gill-sans-family/) if your design depends on it. Beware, though: it isn't free.

Comment: Actually I didn't installed any font styles for Gill Sans in windows But it is working.Why?

Comment: It was probably installed on your computer with some application, [most likely Microsoft Office](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/fonts/font.aspx?FMID=979).

Comment: OK thank you for your clarifications.I have one more doubt that is I am also installed Microsoft Office in Ubuntu also but it is not supported Gill Sans font.why?

Comment: No, you didn't. Microsoft Office is not available for Linux. You may have installed the Windows version of Office under Wine, but this does not make the fonts available outside the Wine environment.

Comment: Which software is used for supporting Gill Sans font in Ubuntu,just likely MS Office in Windows